# JW Player controls not working

Tags: amazon-s3, joomla, jwplayer

I have used JW Player plugin in my joomla website. We have a lot of videos to upload in our website, so we are using Amazon. In the desktop webbrowser the controls of player are working fine. But in mobile and safari webbrowser the controls are not shown properly.

This is the code I have added for amazon tag(`{amazon}{/amazon}`).

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
jwplayer('{SOURCE}').setup({

    'playlist': [{
        sources: [{
        'file':'https://s3.amazonaws.com/qa-mp4format/{SOURCE}'
        },{
        'file':'rtmp://srzg2rz4587c9.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/mp4:{SOURCE}'
        }]
        }],
    'image': '{PLAYER_POSTER_FRAME_REMOTE}',
    'height': '{HEIGHT}',
    'width': '{WIDTH}',
    'autostart': '{PLAYER_AUTOPLAY}',
    'repeat': '{PLAYER_LOOP}',
    'primary': 'flash',
    'controls': '{JWPLAYER_CONTROLS}'
});
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The JW controls will show up by default, so you can take that out of your configuration. Also if you are concerned about your mobile viewer experience, you will not want to force 'flash'.

Comment: Thank You for the reply. If i'm not using flash as primary the controls are not shown in desktop also. In desktop (chrome,firefox), 'rtmp://srzg2rz4587c9.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/mp4:{SOURCE}' is taken and in mobile and safari, https://s3.amazonaws.com/qa-mp4format/{SOURCE} is taken. The controls are not shown when last link(https://s3.amazonaws.com/qa-mp4format/{SOURCE}) is using.